# How can i change "-infinity" to today's date in Google Data Studio or Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, looker-studio

I've got a text field containing different dates and cells containing `-infinity` (meaning today's date).

How can I change `-infinity` to today's date in Google Data Studio or Google Sheets and how do I change the cell from text to date?

The image below contains the column with the dates and `-infinity`.

[image: Column date]

Comment: Bob, please include a link to a sample spreadsheet containing the data shown in your image, being sure to set the link's Share permission to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor." Otherwise, we would be required to manually enter your data into a sheet of our own before we could even begin testing solutions; and that will be a deterrent to getting the help you're seeking in a timely fashion. Conceptually, I know how I'd solve it. But it is neither effective nor efficient to share an untested formula.

Comment: Hi Erik,
Thnx for answering my question. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1N0GvXCAJQ0292l_-m8FmUX-8RYtOpjAwNncyFz_yfrU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the formula already presented in the previous answer, you can also make use of Apps Script in order to achieve your task.

#### Apps Script version

You will have to go to *Tools* > *Script editor* and use the code below which loops through the `A` column and whenever it encounters an `-infinity` value, it replaces it with the current date.

```
function replaceInfinity() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  let validUntil = ss.getRange("A2:A").getValues();
  for (let i=0; i<validUntil.length; i++) 
    if (validUntil[i][0] == "-infinity") 
      ss.getRange(i+2,1).setValue(new Date());
}
```

#### Before

[image: before executing the script]

#### After

[image: after executing the script]

#### Reference

- [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script).

Answer (score 0):

Now that you have added a spreadsheet, I duplicated your raw data sheet and added a processing formula in B1:

`=ArrayFormula({"valid_until V2";IF(A2:A="";;IFERROR(VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A;"\S+"))+VALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A;"\s([^/./+]+)"));DATEVALUE("1/1/2050")))})`

This one array formula produces all results for Column B, including the header (which you can change to whatever you like).

I processed your "infinity" dates to show as the real date January 1, 2050 — a date far enough in the future to essentially serve the same purpose as "no expiration."